# How to define the end of a search string with regex

Tags: regex, search

I am using this regex to search for quotations inside of the value="" that is inside of a string interpreter in a jsp:param

```
(?<=<jsp:param).*(?<=value=").*<%=.*".*(?=%>)
```

It seems to work fine, but it also seems to search for a quote that is inside of a string interpreter that is not inside my jsp:param. Is there anyway to refine the regex to look only inside the value=""?

I apologize if this regex is all kinds of wrong, it is the first time writing regex with any real complexity to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: Can you give an example of the string you are trying to match from?

Comment: It's very unclear what exactly you're trying to match.. it looks like you're trying to get more than just `value="<this bit here>"`

Comment: I am trying to see if the value inside the <jsp:param value="<%=ifThis HasQuotationMark(s)%>" />. So it is a search string in like a search all files (in sublime text). My issue is that it seems to search for a quotation if it is passed the value="" but on the same line.

So it would find it if it was <jsp:param value="<%=someObject.getMethod("argument")%>" />
But Not
This <jsp:param value="<%=stringName%>" />

Answer (score 0):

How about the following (adding ? after .*)?

```
(?<=<jsp:param).*?(?<=value=").*<%=.*".*(?=%>)
```